# Spring Boot Unit test gives error: Cannot invoke "" because "this.taskService" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test my service class and the repository. I want to test whether the code will correctly create and read the data. I mock the repo but when I run the test it just says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "[PROJECTPATH].Services.TaskService.createTask([PROJECTPATH].Models.Task)" because "this.taskService" is null
```

TaskService

```
@Service
public class TaskService implements ITaskService {
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    public Task createTask(Task task) {
        return taskRepository.save(task);
    }

    public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
        return taskRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Task> getTaskById(long id) {
        return taskRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

TaskRepository

```
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {

}
```

Test

```
class TaskServiceTest {
    @MockBean
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;
    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Test
    void createTask() {
        Task task = new Task("bzbz", "some more bzbz");

        Task returnedTask = taskService.createTask(task);

        assert(returnedTask.getTitle()).equals("bzbz");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to annotate your `TaskServiceTest` with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`  or `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`, depending on the version of junit you use, although I'd suggest just using plain Mockito.

Comment: @tgdavies he is using mockito, so he need to use @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)

Comment: @tgdavies neither of those helped

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan ^

Answer (score 1):

You need to do below fixes in your test case and then your issue will be resolved.

1. Add @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) annotation on top of TaskServiceTest class.
2. Replace @MockBean annotation with @Mock on top of TaskRespository instance.
3. Remove @Autowired annotation on top of TaskService instance.
4. Mock save() method of TaskRepository class and then call createTask() method in test case.

Comment: Yes that got rid of the error indeed, thank you. Although now I get the following: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "title" because "returnedTask" is null`. I'm not testing wrong am I?

Comment: Yes please read 4th point

Comment: That will fix this issue

Comment: I believe you mean a line like this: `Mockito.when(taskRepository.save(task)).thenReturn(task);`. I don't understand why people use this line thought, because you're not really testing your service/repository like that right? You're returning a hardcoded value.

Comment: This line doesn’t mean actually testing the service but that is required for mocking the response. In createTask() method you are calling save method of Respository class and that is mocked and without when/then that won’t work

Comment: So when `.save()` method is executed during the test is it being saved in an in-memory db or somewhere? Because that's what I need, I don't want to fake a response. I want to actually test it by saving it in memory and then for example returning all in a later line.

Comment: No it won’t save anywhere. It is just a mock call

Comment: But isn't this pointless if the reponse is fully mocked, than what's the point?

Comment: If you don’t want to mock the response then write integration test case

Comment: You can use @SpringBootTest annotation for that